# CSS Border Not Extending The Entire Div

Tags: javascript, html, height, css

Take a look at the picture below, as you can see i have a border on each side of the div or at least the right side in the div. what i want the border to do is extend the whole grey div but when i put `height:100%;` to the div with the border it appears as it is. examin my css below also and let me explain. `#Content` is the big grey div that contains everything, if i remove min-height and make it `height:70%;` the border extends the whole page. take a look at a before and after picture below to get an idea.

CSS:

```
#Content {
padding:0px;
min-height:70%;
}
```

before:

[image: BEFORE]

After:
[image: AFTER]

changed `#Content {
padding:0px;
min-height:70%;
}`

to `#Content {
padding:0px;
height:70%;
}`

can someone please explain to me how i can get the borders in the "after state picture" with a min-height property. here is a jsFiddle to mess around in : [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/U2MsK/)

Comment: is the PHP tag necessary?

Comment: no not really ill take it off...

Comment: hi is the border in `left` `#content` you want to illuminate

Comment: So you want the borders to go as far down as the end of the text?

Comment: yes @MarcAudet or the min-height of #Content

Comment: by removing the `min-height:50%` from the #Content style seems to produce the desired result?

Comment: Can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @lukeocom if i do that then the whole grey div will shrink i want a min-height and extend the height as content fills beyond i am only able to use a height and im using the latest Google Chrome

Comment: @ArunPJohny i did at the end of my question

Comment: adding border:1px solid #000; to your #CContent style is not what you're after either?? http://jsfiddle.net/U2MsK/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing a bit, but perhaps the effect that you want may result from:

```
#Files {
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    min-height: 20em;
    padding: 0 10px;   
}
```

I made the borders red and wide for clarity, but that can be changed.

To extend the borders all the way to the end of `<div id="Content">`, you need to 
modify the following style:

```
#Content {
    width:100%;
    min-width:965px;
    min-height:50%;
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E5E5E5;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Note that you need to set bottom padding to zero.  If you want to force a space and retain the borders, you need a put in an extra element with a fixed height:

```
<p style="height: 50px; margin: 0;"><!-- spacing hack --></p>
```

This is a quick and dirty way of doing this without modifying the rest of the layout.

Pay attention to your original style sheet, I think that the `#Content` rule appears in a couple of places (lines 4 and 103 in your original fiddle CSS panel).

My fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/TuRUk/1/

Hope this helps!

**Note:** I put in some extra padding but that is optional.  I did not like the text sitting on the border...

**About min-height:**
To get the borders to work as you want, the `#Files` div needs an absolute measurement for its height (a relative one like auto or 100% will not do it).  So, I specify a `min-height` for `#Files` (20em, but you can adjust this) and for small content (a few lines) the borders go all the way to the bottom.  For larger chunks of text, it still works.

Because of the way you floated the other div's, the `#Files` div had no way of knowing the height of a sibling element, the best it can do is inherit a height from its parent, but in this case, the other elements do not factor since they are floated.

Comment: i want the borders to extend the whole grey div.

Comment: but why if i make min-height to height it works but not the other way around?

Comment: I just realized that I did not save my changes to jsFiddle yesterday.  I double checked my work and the fiddle now works as I intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot! what did you change? i cant seem to find that!

Comment: The layout that you are implementing is quite challenging and I think that I saw something similar once in a book by Eric Meyer (a CSS expert).  His books are quite helpful and worth the effort to read and learn.  All the best!